# List from aggregated duplicate objects where a string property concats the strings from the duplicate objects in C#

Tags: c#, linq

There are a lot of similar questions and answers but I didn't find any which matches the criteria I'm searching for.

I have the following list of products:

```
var product = new List<Product> {
  new Product { Name = "apple", Quantity = 1, Store = "1" }, 
  new Product { Name = "orange",Quantity = 2, Store = "2" }, 
  new Product { Name = "apple", Quantity = 3, Store = "3" }, 
  new Product { Name = "lemon", Quantity = 4, Store = "4" } };
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is: a new List which contains only the products with unique Names, where the quantity would be a sum of the Quantities of the products with duplicate names and the string property Store would contain all the stores where the product exists. (Any List or Array could be used for storing the Stores too)
The result I expect for the upper example is:

```
apple   4  1,3 
orange  2  2
lemon   4  4
```

Currently I'm using a nested loop, but searching for a more readable code but not performance.
Using LINQ GroupBy, DistinctItemComparer would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq for sum of distinct addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474475/linq-for-sum-of-distinct-addresses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = product
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        Name = x.Key,
        Quantity = x.Sum(y => y.Quantity),
        Store = string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.Store))
    });
```

The above should be fairly self-explanatory. The GroupBy provides the distinct list of product names. From there, you can aggregate the quantities and stores and project into an anonymous type.

May want to consider adding a distinct clause against the store, i.e., `string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.Store).Distinct())`

Comment: Thank you! string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.Store)) was exactly what I needed.